# React component is rebuilding on every button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write tabs for React and I don't understand why the active class is applied to the button only after the second click on it

```js
import { useState } from "react";

function buttonCreator() {
    const buttonStateChangers = [];
    return function SwitchTabButton({ loadTab, tabContent, tabName }) {
    console.log(`create ${tabName}`)
        const [state, toggleState] = useState("inactive");

        buttonStateChangers.push(toggleState);
        function handleClick() {
            if (state === "active") {
                return;
            }
            buttonStateChangers.forEach((changeState) => {
                changeState("inactive");
            });
            toggleState("active");
            loadTab(tabContent);
        }
        return (
            <button className={state} onClick={handleClick}>
                {tabName}
            </button>
        );
    };
}

export default function Tabs() {
  console.log("create tabs")
    const SwitchTabButton = buttonCreator();
  const [tab, loadTab] = useState(null);
    const tabsData = [
        {
            name: "Button 1",
            content: "Tab 1",
        },
        {
            name: "Button 2",
            content: "Tab 2",
        },
        {
            name: "Button 3",
            content: "Tab 3",
        },
    ];
    return (
        <>
            {tabsData.map((data, index) => {
                return (
                    <SwitchTabButton
                        key={index}
                        loadTab={loadTab}
                        tabName={data.name}
                        tabContent={data.content}
                    />
                );
            })}
            {tab}
        </>
    );
}
```

I noticed that when you click on a button, the Tabs component is rebuilding and therefore the buttons are also rebuilding. I'm guessing this is because the SwitchTabButton has loadTab as an argument and loadTab function is associated with the changed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Tabs` component is dynamically creating the `SwitchTabComponent` on *every* render, meaning that your state is actually lost on rerender. You'd be better off using React context APIs instead (or even a more simple callback for your `Tab` component), doing something like the following:

```
const TabContext = React.createContext({
  activeIndex: 0,
  changeIndex: (index) => {},
});

function Tab({ tabName, tabIndex }) {
  const { activeIndex, changeIndex } = useContext(TabContext);

  // you can now use this to determine whether or not the given Tab component should be in an active state
  const isActive = activeIndex === tabIndex;

  function handleClick() {
    changeIndex(tabIndex);
  }

  return <button className={isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}>{tabName}</button>
}

function Tabs() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const changeIndex = (index) => setActiveIndex(index);

  // ...your tabContents, etc.

  const tabContent = tabContents[activeIndex].content;

  return (
    <TabContext.Provider value={{ activeIndex, changeIndex }}>
      {
        tabContents.map((data, index) =>
          <Tab
            key={index}
            tabName={data.name}
            tabIndex={index} />
        )
      }
      {tabContent}
    </TabContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

React context APIs are useful here if you need to access the "active" tab elsewhere in a nested component tree; otherwise this solution is fairly overkill and you can simply pass `activeIndex` and `changeIndex` as props to your Tab components instead.